# MySQL Column with Dynamic Value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 Tables

1. tbl_jobs as **jobs** *jobs.job_id = job_applicants.job_id*
2. tbl_jobs_applicants as **job_applicants**
3. tbl_applicants as **applicants** *job_applicants.applicant_id = applicants.applicant_id*

I want to show in a view the names of applicants in the job (concatenated with a comma (fname lname)

```
SELECT 
jobs.jobs_id,
{Mark Cruz, Steve Blake, Stephen Raynold}
```

**Here's the my table structure:** 
[image: Table Structure]

Comment: Always try to include your rdbms tag for sql questions `SqlServer`, `MySql`?. Some functions arent available on all databases.

Comment: SO is not a query writing service...you should show us what you've done so far

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I'm using mySQL

Comment: @MegaTron - yes I know, that's why I wrote these:SELECT 
jobs.jobs_id,
{Mark Cruz, Steve Blake, Stephen Raynold}

Comment: @MegaTron - I know how to use CONCAT & UNION. But in my case, It involves 3 tables. That's why it's hard for me to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE `group_concat`

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e755170/12)**

```
SELECT job_id, GROUP_CONCAT(fullname ORDER BY fullname ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS applicants
FROM ( 
    SELECT j.job_id, concat(f_name, ' ', l_name) fullname
    FROM jobs  j
    join job_applicants ja
       on j.job_id = ja.job_id
    join applicants a
       on ja.applicant_id = a.applicant_id
) as j
GROUP BY job_id
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| job_id |             applicants |
|--------|------------------------|
|      1 | emily swan, jhon twain |
|      3 |             jhon twain |
|      4 |             emily swan |
```

Comment: haha, I'm currently reading about this group_concat, thanks bro! I'll check this one and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: check the fiddle, should show you how works. Also try to post the code in text, we cant copy/paste from pictures. Or prepare a fiiddle like mine

Comment: nice answer Juan Carlos

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - thanks! awesome it works! I'll keep that copy/paste or fiddle in mind. Thanks again!